# Pasarle un parametro al metodo trace_add

Tags: python, tkinter

Como están muchachos? mi duda es la siguiente usando **tkinter** tenemos la función **trace_add** para servir de "observador" al cambio de una variable, y para eso la función lleva

```
la_variable.trace_add(modo,función)
```

mi pregunta es...Hay alguna forma de llamar a la función y pasarle otro parámetro mas?(necesito pasarle un numero)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes usar una función que actúe de envoltorio y que no reciba parámetros:

- Usar una función normal como wrapper:

  ```
  import random
  import tkinter as tk


  def trace_callback(var, index, op, value=None):
      print(value)

  def wrapper(*args):
      num = random.randint(1, 100)
      trace_callback(*args, value=num)

  root = tk.Tk()
  root.geometry("300x100")
  var = tk.StringVar(root)
  var.trace_add("write", wrapper)
  tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var).place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)
  root.mainloop()
  ```
- Usar una expresión `lambda`:

  ```
  import random
  import tkinter as tk


  def trace_callback(var, index, op, value=None):
      print(value)

  root = tk.Tk()
  root.geometry("300x100")
  var = tk.StringVar(root)
  var.trace_add("write", lambda *args: trace_callback(*args, random.randint(1, 100)))
  tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var).place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)
  root.mainloop()
  ```

Comment: Gracias soluciono mi problema pero ahora tengo otra duda, que estaría haciendo exactamente trace ? y diferencia tiene trace_callback con trace_add?

Comment: Hola Dewet, disculpa la confusión ha sido un despiste por mi parte, tenía un "typo" realmente ocasionado por el autocompletado de mi IDE. El método `trace` está considerado actualmente como obsoleto (desde Python 3.6), se debe usar `trace_add` como bien haces tú. Aunque actualmente ambos pueden usarse y hacen lo mismo, en un futuro `trace` se eliminará. `trace_callback` es simplemente el nombre que le he dado a la función que se llama cuando el evento se produce, lo que tu llamas `función` en tu ejemplo sin más.

Comment: He editado la respuesta corrigiéndolo, si sigues con alguna duda no te cortes en preguntar. Un saludo.

Comment: Nada que consultar claro como el agua, un millon de gracias amigo!